# Library to programmatically generate python source code?

Tags: java, python, code-generation

I'm looking to create python source code from within a java application. Does such a library exist that will allow easy code generation of python?

Comment: Because python isn't already easy enough? :-)

Comment: are you looking for a java to python conversion thing? or?

Comment: Tell us more, at the moment you are sounding vaguely insane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic solution, if you **really** need to generate `python` code from within `java` :

```
File file = new File("script.py");
FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis);
System.setOut(out);
System.out.println("#!/usr/bin/python");
System.out.println("print 'hello world'");
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve  ???, using a template engine (e.g. [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)) 
is an alternative to using lots of println's. Using velocity would be cleaner but slower than using println's